# How to logout / destroy / unset cakephp 3 php all user session when restart the apache/nginx server

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, server, cakephp-3.x

How to logout / destroy / unset cakephp 3 php all user session when restart the apache/nginx server.
Is it possible?

My client is expecting like, if he restart apache/nginx web server then all logged in user should be logged out automatically.
How this is possible in cakephp 3. Can anyone help or share his/her experience?

I have got this as a requirement of a project, as if server admin restart the apache server then all user session get reset.

I have used below session method at **`/config/app.php`**

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
],
```

Comment: Help me if anyone can,  I have searched alot on google but no help !
And I request to those, please let me know the reason if you downvote this.

Comment: What does that mean, "destroy session"? The session of a specific user? All sessions? You really need to be more specific. And why do you need to do that in the first place? Generally if you need control over sessions outside of the current user/request scope, you usually need to switch to a different session handler, one that gives you easy access to the session data/files/records...

Comment: @ndm I have modified my question, thanks for your  feedback

Comment: You can ask your administrator to write a bash script which cleans up the /tmp folder and then restarts the server.